# Why `+0n` throws an error but `-0n` does not?

Tags: javascript, bigint

The following code throws an error in javascript:

```js
console.log(String(+0n))
```

But this code runs successfully:

```js
console.log(String(-0n))
```

Why `+0n` throws an error but `-0n` does not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So that it [doesn't break asm.js](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#dont-break-asmjs):

> - Unary `+` followed by an expression is always either a Number, or results in throwing. For this reason, unfortunately, `+` on a BigInt
>   needs to throw, rather than being symmetrical with `+` on Number:
>   Otherwise, previously "type-declared" asm.js code would now be
>   polymorphic.

As [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) highlights in the comments, this was the least bad of three options:

1. `+`BigInt -> BigInt: breaks asm.js, and anything else that made the assumption *"unary plus gives a Number"*;
2. `+`BigInt -> Number: conflicts with the [design decision](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#no-implicit-conversions-or-mixed-operands) to disallow implicit conversions between Number and BigInt; or
3. `+`BigInt -> error.

Comment: To be precise, they had three choices: make it return the bigint (which breaks asm.js and probably some developer expectations), make it convert the bigint to a number (which is inconsistent with the design of otherwise forbidding implicit conversions), or throw.

Answer (score 2):

`+0n` is treated as `+(BigInt(0))`, since unary `+` means "cast to integer", and it can't automatically do that (for some reason)

```js
console.log(+(BigInt(0)));
```

`-0n` is treated as `BigInt(-0)`, since negative numbers can be big integers

**(You need to check your console for this, since I guess there's a bug in the StackSnippets preventing BigInts from being casted to a string in the `console.log call`)**

```js
console.log(BigInt(-0));
```

Comment: The strange thing is that `Number(BigInt(0))` doesn't get an error.

Comment: @Barmar That's because `+` is considered an implicit conversion (which are not allowed) but the `Number` function is the only way to convert a bigint to a number

Comment: Did you mean "cast to number" instead of "cast to integer"?

Comment: The second half of this answer is incorrect: `-0n` first creates the BigInt `0`, then negates it (which is a no-op for `0n`), so if anything it's closer to `-BigInt(0)`; however it never creates a Number `0`, and hence never performs a Number-to-BigInt conversion; the source text `0n` is parsed directly to a BigInt.