# Why is unary + incompatible with BigInt?

Tags: javascript

The unary `+` operator throws a TypeError when used with an operand of type BigInt.

```js
console.log(+(1n)) // TypeError
```

The unary `-` operator works just fine with BigInt.

```js
console.log(-(1n)) // -1n (although there appears to be a bug in the behavior of the Stackoverflow code editor, causing this not to render)
```

Why this apparent asymmetry? Is it because of the longstanding idiom of using the unary `+` operator to perform a conversion to `Number`?

Comment: FWIW, if you go to the proposal's issue list and search for "unary" ([link](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues?q=is%3Aissue+unary)) you'll find the answer (which jonrsharpe also provides on the linked question). The "why" for things in ES2015+ can usually be found in the proposal's explainers or issues (it's *so much better* than it was in the old days).

Comment: Quoting @Bergi's comment from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69860416/why-0n-throws-an-error-but-0n-does-not), "To be precise, they had three choices: make it return the bigint (which breaks asm.js and probably some developer expectations), make it convert the bigint to a number (which is inconsistent with the design of otherwise forbidding implicit conversions), or throw [an error]."